# Perl Json parser , changing the order of elements in the json

Tags: json, perl

I am using perl's json module to parse a json object and update it.

After updating the json object we see, that the order of the element inside the json is changed, I understand the order of elements in json doesn't matter.

But wanted to know is there a way i could keep the same order as input json object?Because we share the update json with many clients, I am afraid if some one is using a parser where the order of element is hard coded.

Comment: Can you share some code that you are using to read and modify the JSON object

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use some sort of tied hash to enforce the order of the keys: [Tie::IxHash](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::IxHash).

The following is a proof of concept:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

use JSON::XS;

my $JSON = JSON::XS->new->utf8->indent->space_after->convert_blessed;

my $data = {
    a => 1,
    b => 2,
    c => 3,
    d => 4,
    e => 5,
};

say $JSON->encode($data);      # Keys are unordered

bless $data, 'MyAlphaHash';

say $JSON->encode($data);      # Keys are alphabetized

package MyAlphaHash;

use Tie::IxHash;

sub TO_JSON {
    my $self = shift;

    tie my %hash, 'Tie::IxHash', %$self;

    tied(%hash)->Reorder( sort keys %hash );

    return \%hash;
}
```

Outputs:

```
$ perl ordered.pl
{
   "e": 5,
   "c": 3,
   "a": 1,
   "b": 2,
   "d": 4
}

{
   "a": 1,
   "b": 2,
   "c": 3,
   "d": 4,
   "e": 5
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code snippet does not help for the quite common scenario "manipulate a json file, but preserve the ordering of hashes". What's missing is the JSON decoding part, which would need to deserialize all json objects into Tie::IxHash objects (or something similar). To my knowledge, neither JSON::XS nor Cpanel::JSON::XS can do this.